# Converting string hours and minutes into Days/Hours/Minutes in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, timespan

I have the sum of the working duration of Employees in a specific period. I need to convert this Working Duration into days, hours and minutes. The problem is my day is equal to 9 Hours, not 24 Hours. Means I am dividing my Duration with 9. But the result I am getting is in points and I can't convert to my yearning format. Following is my code:

```
var Durations = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(db.Attendances.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == id)
                .Sum(x => TimeSpan.Parse(x.Duration).TotalMinutes));

var TotalDuration = string.Format("{0}:{1}", Durations.TotalHours, Durations.Minutes);
```

This one is working absolutely fine. I am getting results in the following format:

```
H:M
8:5
12:7
19:15
```

The problem is I need to convert hours into Days and Hours when I divide it by 9. E.g. 19. If I divide 19 by 9 I get 2.111111 Means 2 Days and 1 Hour. How can I get the answer in days and hours format?

Comment: what is your rounding mechanism?

Comment: I am using Math.Truncate.

Comment: what is wrong with: Days = Durations.TotalHours / 9; Hours = Durations.TotalHours % 9; Minutes = Durations.Minutes; TotalDuration = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", Days, Hours, Minutes); ?

Comment: I want to convert my Hours into Days and Hours. Day duration is 9 hours, not 24.

Comment: so what I suggested should work...

Comment: @oviuan: That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @oviuan it worked. I just had to do Math.Truncate to avoid decimal part.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should answer your question:

```
   TimeSpan s = new TimeSpan(20,0, 0);
        int day = (int)s.TotalHours / 9;
        int hour = (int)s.TotalHours % 9;
        Console.WriteLine($"the duration in day is {day } hour {hour}");
```

Comment: Why `((int)s.TotalMinutes - (day*9 * 60))/60` instead of simply doing `s.TotalHours % 9`? (I don't get why you're using total minutes instead of total hours to begin with)

Comment: yes you're right flater, it's just the same andl simplified the logic.

Comment: Minor nitpick: Since you're only entering hours in the `TimeSpan` and only using `TotalHours` from the `TimeSpan`, you could just use an `int` instead of a `TimeSpan`. The current code doesn't actually rely on any `TimeSpan` logic.

Comment: yes it is, but from the question context above the code has timespan type instead of regular int. this is just to ensure that it is work for above scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extension method to TimeSpan.

```
public static (int day,int hour) GetDayAndHour(this TimeSpan timeSpan,int dayDuration == 9) {

        var  number= timeSpan.TotalHours/dayDuration;
        int day  = (int)Math.Truncate(number);
        int hour= (int)Math.Truncate((number-day)*10);
        return (day,hour);
}
```

I use C#7 tuple.If you use previous version, create costume datatype or use `Tuple<int, int>`.

Comment: Is this valid c# syntax?

Comment: Yes, with c#7  tuples, it is

Comment: Cool thing. I'd recommend to post this with c#6 anyway as most ppl still use c#6

Answer (score 0):

```
int totalmins = 5000; // given input
int hourPerDay = 9 // given input
int dayHour = 60 * hourPerDay;
int days = totalmins / dayHour;
int hours = (totalmins % dayHour) / 60;
int mins = tot_mins % 60;
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old, well answered question, please explain how it complements the other answers.